# default sort in lucene.net

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

My index contains ~4 million recrords.

When I sort the results, the query runs much slower, which is not surprising.

My question is, is there some way to create the index so that when I make a call and don't pass a sort, it sorts by field I most recently use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By default lucene returns the results in an order, which depends on the relevance.
As far as i know, you have to use the boost, the sort function or something else if you like an other listing order.
What ever you take - the results will not return faster by using an sort or boost function.

Comment: Boosting will (usually) be faster than sorting, since you can limit the number of returned results, which is a [major factor of Lucene's performance](http://philosophyforprogrammers.blogspot.com/2010/09/lucene-performance.html).